# Rename [responses] to [responses-tab]

Tags: discussion, meta, retag-request

I noticed that the tag [responses](/questions/tagged/responses), whose wiki says it's about the "responses" tab in one's own user profile, is being used for many different purposes that are not related to that specific tab.

Can we please make the tag's purpose clear by changing its name to [responses-tab](/questions/tagged/responses-tab), and retagging the incorrect uses?